# How do I build a query for this?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
| bed_id | bed_num | place_id  | bed_date   |
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
|      1 |     150 |         1 | 1244344305 |
|      2 |     250 |         1 | 1244345469 |
|      3 |     145 |         2 | 1244348496 | 
|      3 |     146 |         2 | 1244348497 | 
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to select all the unique `place_id`s with most recent date of `bed_num` so it should return something like below:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
| bed_id | bed_num | place_id  | bed_date   |
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
|      2 |     250 |         1 | 1244345469 |
|      3 |     146 |         2 | 1244348497 | 
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I have tried mixing GROUP BY and ORDER BY using distinct(place_id) AND max(bed_date)

But failing!

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to get some aggregated data (place_id, bed date), and other non-aggregate data (bed_id and bed_num), you need to use a subselect to do the aggregate, then join on it as if it was an anonymous view:

```
SELECT bed_id, bed_num, place_id, bed_date
FROM beds
INNER JOIN (SELECT place_id, MAX(bed_date) FROM beds GROUP BY place_id) max_dates
ON max_dates.place_id = beds.place_id AND max_dates.bed_date = beds.bed_date
```

Otherwise, your aggregate "group by" will apply to all your columns, and you'll end up with a (potentially random) bed_id and bed_num from the aggregate

Comment: with a little syntax corrections that works perfectly, thank you so much!, I've been grinding my head all day. Since the query itself is in another queries subselect there is a total of 2 subselects now, will that be a problem, performance vise

Comment: I've had them nested 4 to 5 deep without a problem; but it really depends on the structure. I'd try it and see, then fix if necessary.